# Git push error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502

Tags: git, version-control

i have a problem to push my commits ,i have several commits to push at once and i have the following error:

$ git push origin SHA:feature/version
Enumerating objects: 2150, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2081/2081), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1552/1552), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1881/1881), 429.22 MiB | 3.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 1881 (delta 742), reused 61 (delta 20)
efatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
rror: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502
Everything up-to-date

initially i made  a mistake by pushing target folder that contains big files ,but i corrected it my removing it from versionning .
but when pushing on VCS i have still the unversionned folders in gray colour.
does GIT still include them ??
i want a command or a solution that would allow me may be to make small pushes .

Answer (score 0):

finally the problem was the lack in memory in intellij ,i succeded to push after performing it in gitbash.
the error message is misleading ,i thought that there i had a big push memory which was bigger that the memory of the entreprise VPN.